# Google Glass: Saved video is invisible on Windows explorer

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to save a video I recorded with google glass using surfaceView & android camera api, but I can't see the result file when I connect the glass to windows.
on ADB it's there:

```
shell@android:/sdcard/pictures $ ls
ls
myVideo_1393761357271.mp4
myVideo_1393761421585.mp4
myVideo_1393761466723.mp4
shell@android:/sdcard/pictures $
```

but on windows explorer my videos are not seen. even when I tried to create a directory it is not shown on windows. I tried the DCIM folder also, and same thing there.
[image]

How can I create a video file in a directory which is visible to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The problem was solved by itself. but only a long while after. there is a strange delay between the time of the file creation until it appears in the windows explorer. I tried disconnecting & reconnecting the glasses but none of it worked. today (one day after) I connected the glasses and there it was.